# Protected Internal method not allowing Internal Class as parameter

Tags: c#

This code does not compile:

```
internal class Foo {}

public abstract class SomeBaseClass
{
    protected internal void ProcessFoo(Foo value)
    {
        // doing something...
    }
}
```

The compile fails stating:

**Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type `Foo` is less accessible than method `SomeBaseClass.ProcessFoo`**

Comment: The compiler is correct: `internal` is less accessible than `protected internal`, which means `protected` OR `internal`. A class in another assembly may derive from `SomeBaseClass` and call `ProcessFoo`. Either change the accessibility of `ProcessFoo` to `internal`, or change the accessibility of `Foo` to `public`.

Comment: This is good enough to be an answer, @MichaelLiu

Comment: Oh I understand, I thought protected internal is additive (protected, internal) not alternative (protected/internal). That is unfortunate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `protected internal` means `protected` or `internal` and not `protected` and `internal` as I had believed.

Credit to Michael Liu

Comment: I'd also add you can get the effect of `protected` AND `internal` by using the `private protected` modifier as [outlined here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers). (Which, confusingly, does not mean "`private` or `protected`" but something else entirely.)

Comment: Shoulda just gone with `private protected internal` at that point.